# How to configure an ACL on ASA when the inside source IP address is translated by NAT?

Tags: nat, acl

[image]

I don't know how to configure an ACL when inside source nat is enabled.

In my example, I want to realize bidirectional communication with TCP port 30000 between 172.16.100.100(inside) and 10.10.10.10(outside), and translating 172.16.100.100 into 200.200.200.200 is needed.

Also, I need to configure ACL permitting traffic between the two nodes.
I've heard NAT is processed before ACL, so the ACLs below are correct?

access-list outside-in extended permit tcp host 10.10.10.10 host 172.16.100.100 eq 30000

access-list inside-in extended permit tcp host 200.200.200.200 host 10.10.10.10 eq 30000

Any help will be appreciated...

Comment: We need to see the full sanitized configs for both sides (if possible). Both of the subnets (before NAT) that you listed are private subnets, so to go over the internet you either need to NAT to public IP addresses on both ends or have them talk through some other means like a site-to-site VPN tunnel.  We can't just guess at these things though, so we need to see the configs.

Comment: Just google Cisco ASA interface packet flow order, and you will see in what order various services are applied as the packet flows through the interfaces and then you will know how to apply ACL properly

Comment: @MattDouhan That is bad advice to give without seeing the full configs to know how the sites are connected.  Your attempt to help is appreciated but should wait until more information is provided by the OP.

Comment: @JesseP. Understanding the packet flow and order of services is a basic requirement that doesn’t need configs or diagrams, it’s a basic skill set that will not only solve the question once understood it will greatly benefit the OP going forwards as well

Comment: @MattDouhan I agree that it should be known anyway, but blanketly saying that it will answer the OP's questions is not what this site is about.  Part of the job of those that offer help is to read between the lines to make sure that questions that haven't actually been asked have been answered too, and in order to do that we need to know how the devices are configured and connected to each other.  Like I said initially, those are private subnets, and private subnets are not routed over the internet without first NAT'ing to public IP addresses or encapsulating traffic within a tunnel.

Comment: @JesseP. That’s the beauty of my comment, it doesn’t matter if those are private or public subnets, it doesn’t matter how they are connected, it doesn’t matter if they are NaTd or not, by understanding the flow of services the OP will be able to resolve any and all of those situations.

Comment: @MattDouhan Like I said, I agree it's good to know that anyway.  As a comment, I suppose it's fine.